# Remove all fields except some

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**Create a function, which removes all fields except 'firstName' and 'lastName' from the objects.**

This is the code I've written. Any recommendations?

```
let people = [
    {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Clark',
        gender: 'male'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Kaily',
        lastName: 'Berserk',
        gender: 'female'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Steven',
        lastName: 'Bergeron',
        gender: 'male'
    }
];

function removeAllExceptNames(arr) {
    let first = 'firstName';
    let last = 'lastName';

    return arr.forEach(p => {
        if (p !== first || p !== last) {
            delete arr[p];
        }
    })
}

console.log(removeAllExceptNames(people));
console.log(people);
```

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: try map with destructuring if you are using es2015 or babel/ts, some kind of:
const onlyNames = people.map(({firstName, lastName}) => ({firstName, lastName})); do the trick

Comment: Doesn't work. I've also tried to get the keys with 'Óbject keys' but the keys become '0, 1, 2'

Comment: `p` references the object itself, not its keys so `p !== first` doesn't work. If you want to use `delete` you'll need to iterate the keys inside the forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 arguments in the function, the `arr` and the `names`

`arr` is the given array, `names` is the list of fields you want to keep in the array

I used `forEach` twice.. the first time was for the `arr`, the second time was for the **Object's** `keys` for each index in `arr` and *that* is where the exception names can be related to fields in the array of objects

```js
let people = [
    {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Clark',
        gender: 'male'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Kaily',
        lastName: 'Berserk',
        gender: 'female'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Steven',
        lastName: 'Bergeron',
        gender: 'male'
    }
];

function removeAllExceptNames(arr,names) { //arr is the same, names is a list of names you want to keep
  arr.forEach(a=>{
    Object.keys(a).forEach(b=>{
      if(!names.includes(b)){delete(a[b])}
    })
  })
}

removeAllExceptNames(people,["firstName","lastName"]);
console.log(people);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `map` along with `Object.fromEntries` to get the expected output:

```js
const people = [ { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Clark', gender: 'male' }, { firstName: 'Kaily', lastName: 'Berserk', gender: 'female' }, { firstName: 'Steven', lastName: 'Bergeron', gender: 'male' }];

const keepProp=(arr, keepProp)=>arr.map(o=>Object.fromEntries(keepProp.map(n=>[n,o[n]])));

console.log(keepProp(people, ['firstName','lastName']))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to understand what the keyword **delete** does. The Mozilla Foundation says

> The JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object; if no more references to the same property are held, it is eventually released automatically.

In your scenario, you successfully removed the reference but the list is not re-ordered. It only gets replaced with an undefined. We can achieve the same thing by using the splice array function. This will remove the element and re-order.

```
function removeAllExceptNames(arr,firstName,lastName) {
     let instancesOfNamesInArray = arr.filter(e => e.firstName == firstName || e.lastName == lastName);
     // We loop through this instances and remove them from the array
     instancesOfNamesInArray.foreach((item) => {
          arr.splice(arr.indexOf(item),1); // Will remove the item from the array
     });
}
```